# How would I debug this IE7 issue?

Tags: java, javascript, apache-flex, debugging

## Problem:

[Obscure error message http://img66.imageshack.us/img66/6746/confusedg.png](http://img66.imageshack.us/img66/6746/confusedg.png)

### Conditions:

IE7, SP2, latest flash/java. Only reproducible on one machine.

### Observations:

Smaller than a javascript alert box, and seems to be generated when a swf on my web page loads. The dialog is modal, however, like an alert box.

### Issues:

I've tried matching the configuration of the machine in question, but a recreation of the machine does not get this error. I'm not ultra-familiar with flash/flex, so is there something that flex/flash could do which would cause this error dialog to appear.

How would one even go about debugging this? It's mostly not reproducible aside from a single machine, and the circumstances which cause the error are unknown. Thoughts?

Comment: Furthermore, this doesn't seem to break the operation of my flex application, although it is annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a windows dialog to me. Neither Flash/Flex or Javascript. (though one could make either look like that if they tried).

The problem could be entirely machine dependent, it could be a virus, or it could be anti-virus or add blocker thinking the flash file is a threat. My automatic backup.recovery software sometimes pops alerts like that when it's in the middle of making a backup and I download something.

I'm meandering, my point is there are far more variables than just the browser and flash versions that could be coming in to play. I know that probably doesn't help much, but hopefully I've given you a few more ideas of what to check.

Comment: As it turns out, this WAS somehow being generated in the flex with some odd timing issue. The issue is being investigated, but using the app in a high latency/low bandwidth scenario was the only way to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting up the "mirror" of your development machine, are you sure you're installing the version of Flash with Debugging enabled?

That might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using IE developer toolbar? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Process Explorer would help debug this by displaying the call stacks of the IE7 process. You could then look at each call stack in order to find the one displaying the message box. This will show you exactly which modules are on the stack at the time the message box is displayed.